# Comparing an entity with array using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, entity-framework

I have a `string array` named `batches` that contains batchnames. I want to compare it with `Batch entity` and get all the records that matches with batchName field of entity. I am using `Entity Framework 6`.

```
class Batch   
{  
   int batchId { get; set;}  
   string batchname { get; set;}  
   string info { get; set;}  
   DateTime date { get; set;}  
}
```

Right now I am doing it like this using `foreach`

```
foreach(var item in batches)
{
   var res=opt.Batch.Where(i=>i.batchname==item).FirstOrDefault();
   batchlist.Add(res);
}
```

How can I do it with `LINQ` without using `foreach`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the whole foreach loop and keep the 2 lines of code, replacing `i.batchname==item` with the following:

```
batches.Contains(i.batchname)
```

You can then add all items at once to your list as this will return all batches where the name is in the batches array.

The variable res will return an enumerable which can then either be looped around to add to your list or you can use a list that allows AddRange()

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like:

```
var batchlist = opt.Batch.Where(x => batches.Contains(x.batchname)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below will help.

```
foreach(var item in batches)
{
  batchlist.AddRange(opt.Batch.Where(i=>i.batchname.Any(item => i.batchname==item)).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a list of Batch objects:

```
var resultList = opt.Batch.Join(batches, left => left.batchname, right => right, (left, right) => left
```

changing the last 'left' to 'right', will give you a string list of batch names

```
var resultList = opt.Batch.Join(batches, left => left.batchname, right => right, (left, right) => right
```